# E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude:2: Extra junk after value

Tags: 20.04, aptitude

I get this error when opening Synaptic.
I had previously attempted to remove of all the languages in the file system besides English.
Could I have help to fix this error?
Thanks in Advance

```
Aptitude::Get-Root-Command "sudoAcquire::Languages "none";
Acquire::Languages "none";
```

Comment: Fix the junk at the end of line 2 of /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude. Please update your question with the content of that file if you want help.

Comment: I'm not sure what I need to do. I tried removing line 2 as well as replacing it with the lines offered by MURU and still get the error when opening Synaptic..

Comment: My 00aptitude contains only one line: `Aptitude::Get-Root-Command "sudo:/usr/bin/sudo":`

Answer (score 1):

I removed both lines and saved it. Now I can open Synaptic.